# Meaning of this sentence

Tags: meaning

I wondered if somebody could help me with the meaning of the word "slash" in this context.

"Between the slashes of sunlight, the glass mirrored the old scar carved just below his
breastbone"

Is it like a syn of rays of light.

Thanks

Comment: You should always cite the source of quoted text.

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed meant as a synonym for *rays*. But it is not at all a common usage. The author chose it for the imagery. The notion of sharpness and cutting that is implicit in *slash* fits with the mention of the scar, especially given the mention of glass, which is fragile, can end up in shards, and could then slash flesh and thus lead to scarring.